# 「file:///」link does not work within PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap 2.1.0 and iOS 6.0

After I opened external site in PhoneGap,
From the external site, I want to come back to the local html.
However, I cannot move to local "index.html" file with "file:///" URL.
How to move to local html from external site?

example:

```
<a href="file:///Users/hoge/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/HelloWorld.app/www/index.html">Home</a>
```

I send the path of index.html to the server at launch application using Ajax.
The server cached the path and displays a link.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Open your file `Cordova.plist`
- Set the parameter `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView` to `YES`
- Right click on `ExternalHosts` -> `Add Row`
- Set the `String` value of the new added row to `*`.

So your new added row should look like something like this:

```
Item0         String         *
```

For more information about the above, check the online doc: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide .

Let me know if this solution works for you.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the plist setting. and can display the page of other servers (http://example.com/index.html). However, I can't return to HTML of the application local (file:///〜/index.html).

Comment: I think you need to use the complete path instead of `~` because `~` may be defined only on your computer

Comment: I know that a file path changes by platforms. Therefore I send a file path to the server at the launch of the application.